# Java string to date convert null, writing to SQL database issue

Tags: java, sql, parsing, simpledateformat

I have a `Date` that has been converted to a `String` to be passed to a Java `Socket` server. An example of this value is `06:19:18p.m. 13/01/2011`.

Within the `Socket` server I'm trying to convert it back to a `Date` value before writing it to a SQL Database table, but the converted value is `NULL`. I have also tried writing the value to the SQL database as the original `String`, but it doesn't write unless there are no colon, full stop, or forward-slash characters in it.

Is there any way I can get around this?  I'm sorry that I can't view or post the stack trace, as I don't have admin access to the server I'm running my Jar file on.

My code to convert the `String` is:

```
Date date = null;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ssa dd/MM/yyyy");
try { 
    date = sdf.parse(timestamp);
} 
catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Why not just pass the date as is since, by what you said, all your going to do is convert it back to a date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you can't parse correctly but you are thinking all wrong about this. Instead of saving String in the database you should make the column of type TIMESTAMP or DATE. Then you can use getDate() from the JDBC to just get the date object.

Comment: I was trying getDate() in my socket server and column value as a timestamp in SQL but that wasn't working for me either, I'll try that approach again and post results after, cheers.

Comment: JDBC also has a getTimestamp() method if needed.

Comment: Everything method of getting a date I tried worked locally, but not when I uploaded the JAR onto the server, which is strange but I couldn't debug cause of no access. But I got it working in the end, didn't retrieve it using JAVA, in the SQL string I used GETDATE() instead of a variable. Think that was the way you were saying Amir, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The "a" in your SimpleDateFormat pattern can only parse "AM" or "PM", but not "p.m.". Just change that and your parsing will be successful.

Answer (score 0):

This might just be a typo but your example of "06:19:18p.m. 13/012011" does not match your simple date format because it expecting two slashes in your date.

It would be very useful to find a way to get the stack track or try this code out on the data separately elsewhere so that you can make sure you aren't just getting bad data.

Comment: Yes I typed that by accident there, my code has both slashes. Yes maybe using my own computer as a local server to run the Jar file on might help things there..